# Cleanest way to get associated UIView from UIButton press handler

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I have three UIButtons, each with an associated UIView. When one of the buttons is pressed, I want to:

1. Highlight the pressed button
2. Un-highlight the other buttons
3. Hide the UIViews associated with the other buttons
4. Un-hide the UIView associated with the pressed button

My solution (below) works and isn't horrible, but I can't help but think there's a cleaner, more efficient way. Any suggestions?

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSArray *buttonArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:button1, button2, button3, nil];

    NSDictionary* buttonViewDict = @{button1.titleLabel.text : view1,
                                     button2.titleLabel.text : view2,
                                     button3.titleLabel.text : view3};

    for (UIButton* button in buttonArray) {
        [button setHighlighted:[button isEqual:sender]];
        [((UIView*)[buttonViewDict objectForKey:button.titleLabel.text]) setHidden:![button isEqual:sender]];
    }
}
```

Comment: I would do it just like how you did.

Comment: I'd do it the same way, although if the buttons and views aren't dynamic, I'd consider defining the Array and Dictionary only once :)

Comment: You can use buttons in the outlet collection. Also why you need buttonViewDict, when you can use the property of the button? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tag` property to identify your buttons and views.

Set up the tag values in Interface Builder or in `-viewDidLoad`, then use the tag value to identify which button was pressed:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    for (UIButton* button in _buttons) {
        button.highlighted = button.tag == sender.tag;
    }
    for (UIView* view in _views) {
        view.hidden = view.tag != sender.tag;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I like your way. I would consider using the buttons as the keys and simplifying it like so -

```
NSDictionary *buttonViewDict = @{button1 : view1,
                                 button2 : view2,
                                 button3 : view3};

[buttonViewDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, UIView *view, BOOL *stop) {
    view.hidden = !button.highlighted = sender == button;
}];
```

You may also want to store the dictionary as a property.

Comment: I really love this answer. Didn't know about the enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock method. Unfortunately UIButtons can't be used as dictionary keys because they don't conform to NSCopying.

Comment: Ah yes, that's a shame.